# OO Design issue - is this an anti-pattern, or an appropriate place for a pattern/technique I don't know of?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm currently completing a project in PHP, but the general principles of OO still apply.

I have a parent class called Node, which is abstract - i.e. it cannot be instantiated. There are many classes that extend Node, and are instantiable. Some of these include Event, Person, and Project.

The issue I'm having is that I often need to instantiate a Node without knowing which child class it will be. All Node and node-sub-classes always takes the same type of object (a row from a database) as an argument to the constructor. To get around the problem of not knowing what type of implementing class I need, I created a simple static class that will return the correct sub-class of node. An example of this code is as follows:

```
<?php

class NodeClassRegistry{

    public static function init_class($node) {
        switch ($node->type) {
            case 'person':
                return new Person($node);

            case 'event':
                return new Event($node);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

This seems like really bad design to me - it's kind of a factory pattern, but it seems really tied to global state. Is there a design pattern that would be appropriate for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is a special type of the [Factory Method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method#Descriptive_names) The C++ example for this subtype in the [GoF book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is the following:

```
class Creator {
public:
  virtual Product* Create(ProductId id);
}

Product* Creator::Create(ProductId id) {
  if (id == MINE) return new MyProduct;
  if (id == YOURS) return new YourProduct;
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) design pattern, and this is pretty fine to depend on some kind of `type` field/variable to check instance of which underlying type should be created by a factory. See example of Abstract Factory implementation on Java language, it reading global variable from a config file...

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I would store the full class name in a column and create it using reflection. If my memory serves correctly, I could apply the "convention over configuration", that is:

Create classes whose name equals values found in type column

Then, create a function made this way:

```
public static function init_class($node) {
    $item = NULL;
    eval "\$item = new " . $node->type . "(\$node);"
    return $item;
}
```